# Why is my scale-in policy not overriding Auto Scaling Group Desired Capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I seem to be doing something wrong here, and it seems simple but my attempts to resolve have been unsuccessful. I have an Auto Scaling Group with the following configuration:

```
Min: 1
Max: 5
Desired Capacity: 1
```

I have a scale-out policy based on an SQS queue, which is triggered when my CloudWatch Alarm is in ALARM state (messages > 1000):

`Add 1 instances when 1000 <= ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible < 2000
 Add 1 instances when 2000 <= ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible < 4000
 Add 2 instances when 4000 <= ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible <+ infinity`

When I test this policy by matching the expected message load, all instances are added as expected. The Auto Scale Group has a modified Desired Capacity of 5, also as expected.

I have a scale-in policy that is triggered when the CloudWatch Alarm is in OK state (messages < 1000):

`Set to 1 instances`

This does not seem to take effect. The Auto Scale Group remains at the Desired Capacity of 5, instead of being updated by this policy, back to 1 instance.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it eventually scaledown? The default cooldown is 300 seconds.

Comment: @ajtrichards no, never scales down.

Comment: That is odd. May be worth raising with AWS Support if you can.

Comment: Thanks for looking @ajtrichards. I deleted everything and started again, and it downscaled as expected. Must have been some silly mistake along the way.